# Access Nested Objects in v-for Loop

Tags: vue.js, nested, nuxt.js, v-for

I have an API that returns an array of objects. Each object in the array looks like this.

```
{
    id: 6,
    typeTitle: 'Type Title goes here',
    typeImg: 'Some image',
    typeLink: 'https://www.somewebsite.com',
    publishDate: 'Apr 24, 2020',
    typeAuthor: {
      id: 3,
      authorName: 'Pat wilson',
      created_at: '2020-04-24T14:03:54.140Z',
      updated_at: '2020-04-24T14:03:54.140Z'
    },
    stage: {
      id: 1,
      stageTitle: 'Revolve Stage',
      created_at: '2020-04-24T14:11:55.364Z',
      updated_at: '2020-04-24T14:11:55.364Z'
    },
    created_at: '2020-04-24T13:56:01.607Z',
    updated_at: '2020-04-24T14:17:13.543Z',
    categories: []
  }
```

I am using a v-for loop to render an array of such objects. I am not able to access any of the nested objects.

```
<div v-for="(type, index) in types" :key="index">
            <div>
                <img :src="type.typeImg" />
                <div>
                    <p>{{type.typeTitle}} </p>

                    <p>{{type.typeAuthor.authorName}}</p>
                    <div>
                        <template v-for="cat in type.categories">
                            <span :key="cat.categoryName">{{cat.categoryName}}</span>
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am not able to access authorName. The error message that I get is "Cannot read property 'authorName' of undefined"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach; it should work. Most likely, the exact data of `type` isn't what you believe it is. You might try the Vue.js debug tools browser extension to inspect the data of your component and look at `type` to see whether it really has a `typeAuthor` attribute. Alternatively, a quick and dirty debug trick is just to replace the loop contents with `<pre>{{ type }}</pre>` to see what object you're working with.

Comment: your only showing 1 object not an array, one of em doesn't contain typeAuthor

Comment: Thanks. One of the type objects had typeAuthor set to null. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code

```
           types:[
                {
                    id: 6,
                    typeTitle: 'Type Title goes here',
                    typeImg: 'Some image',
                    typeLink: 'https://www.somewebsite.com',
                    publishDate: 'Apr 24, 2020',
                    typeAuthor: {
                    id: 3,
                    authorName: 'Pat wilson',
                    created_at: '2020-04-24T14:03:54.140Z',
                    updated_at: '2020-04-24T14:03:54.140Z'
                    },
                    stage: {
                    id: 1,
                    stageTitle: 'Revolve Stage',
                    created_at: '2020-04-24T14:11:55.364Z',
                    updated_at: '2020-04-24T14:11:55.364Z'
                    },
                    created_at: '2020-04-24T13:56:01.607Z',
                    updated_at: '2020-04-24T14:17:13.543Z',
                    categories: []
                }
        ]


                        <div v-for="(type, index) in types" :key="index">
                        <div>
                            <img :src="type.typeImg" />
                            <div>
                                <p>{{type.typeTitle}} </p>

                                <p>{{type.typeAuthor.authorName}}</p>
                                <div>
                                    <template v-for="cat in type.categories">
                                        <span :key="cat.categoryName"> 
                                   {{cat.categoryName}}</span>
                                    </template>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

He gave me the desired result and the value appeared

[image]